# YOLO- Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

Tags: python, neural-network, google-colaboratory, yolo

I've trained a yolov4 neural network to detect pens. Everything has gone currectly, but when I try to test my model, its just not working. Here's what it's showing-

[image]

Here's the command-

```
!./darknet detector test data/obj.data cfg/yolov4-custom.cfg /mydrive/YOLOV4/training/yolov4-custom_last.weights /mydrive/image1.jpeg 
imShow('predictions.jpg')
```

I dont know if this is relevant, but here's the imshow function-

```
def imShow(path):
  import cv2
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  %matplotlib inline

  image = cv2.imread(path)
  height, width = image.shape[:2]
  resized_image = cv2.resize(image,(3*width, 3*height), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

  fig = plt.gcf()
  fig.set_size_inches(18, 10)
  plt.axis("off")
  plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(resized_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
  plt.show()
```

Someone please help me fix this issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: maybe you should check your network environment.

Comment: Are you running this on Colab?

Comment: yes, i am doing it on colab